# DISTINCT and AVG with 3 columns

Tags: mysql, sql, select, average, distinct

I have  columns

id_employe, id_job and col_int

I need to group id_employe if the employe has the same id_job and from with this id_job i need avg of the third column

I wrote this:

```
DISTINCT(id_employe), id_job, AVG(col_int)
FROM table
```

then I wrote this:

```
DISTINCT(id_employe), id_job, AVG(col_int)
FROM table
GROUP BY id_employe
```

then I tried this:

```
SELECT 
AVG(col_int)
FROM 
(SELECT DISTINCT(id_employe), id_job, AVG(col_int)
FROM table) v
```

I´m lost :(
Thanks for help

Comment: DISTINCT is not a function, it's a _set quantifier_, and works on the whole selected rows. Simply do `SELECT DISTINCT c1, c2 ...` to make code clearer.

Comment: However, GROUP BY eliminates duplicates, so no need to also do SELECT DISTINCT.

Comment: Make it easy to assist you, show us some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text (no images.) [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

You can try this, I hope this helps you.

```
SELECT id_employe, id_job, AVG(col_int)
  FROM table
  GROUP BY id_employe, id_job
```